# apportable - cannot load project

Tags: android, ios, apportable

today I'm downloaded the apportable , first i tried the Spin Sample project and its run on my android device but for the second time when I'm want to run that sample app (Spin) or any other Xcode (iOS) projects i get the following error :

```
Error: Incorrect platform for target; found macosx for project "xxxxxxxxx"
```

im also tried these but nothing changed ! :

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode4.app/Contents/Developer
```

&

```
(echo; echo PATH=~/.apportable/SDK/bin:$PATH) >> ~/.bash_profile; source ~/.bash_profile
```

Comment: You may need to show exactly what you typed and what other output came out before the "Error" message

Comment: Try to check your `config.json` file  "default_target": {"project": "YOUR_PROJECT_NAME", "project_config": "Release", "target": "SHOULD_BE_YOUR_IOS_TARGET"},